# How does one rigorously define two-point functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, correlation-functions, greens-functions

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $\mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$ be its associated bosonic (+) and fermionic (-) Fock spaces. Given $f \in \mathscr{H}$, we can define rigorously the creation and annihilation operators $a^{*}(f)$ and $a(f)$ (see, e.g. [Bratteli & Robinson](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-09089-3)). These operators are densely defined on $D(\sqrt{\mathcal{N}})$, where $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the number operator.

Given a second quantized Hamiltonian $H$ on $\mathcal{F}(\mathscr{H})$, the time evolution of such operators in the Heisenberg picture are given by:
$$e^{iHt}a^{*}(f)e^{-iHt} \quad \mbox{and} \quad e^{iHt}a(f)e^{-iHt}$$

To make the connection between these definitions and the usual definitions in the physics literature, consider the set $\mathcal{D}_{0}$ formed by those vectors $\psi = (\psi_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$ with only finitely many nonzero entries $\psi_{n}$ and:
$$D_{\mathscr{S}} := \{\psi \in \mathcal{D}_{0}: \mbox{$\psi_{n} \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{3n})$ for every $n$}\}$$
Then, we formally write:
$$a^{*}(f) = \int dx f(x)a_{x}^{*} \quad \mbox{and} \quad a(f) = \int dx \overline{f(x)}a_{x}$$
and the formal integral operators are well-defined as quadratic forms on $D_{\mathscr{S}}$.

Analogously, one can consider formal operators:
$$a^{*}_{x}(t) := e^{itH}a_{x}^{*}e^{-itH} \quad \mbox{and} \quad a_{x}(t) := e^{itH}a_{x}e^{-itH}$$

I have two related questions regarding these objects.

1. The quadratic forms $\langle \psi, a_{x}^{*}(t)\varphi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi, a_{x}(t)\varphi\rangle$, with $\psi, \varphi \in D_{\mathscr{S}}$, are not well-defined like this, because these need to be integrated out in $x$. But then, how to properly define/understand two point (or Green) functions:
   $$G(x,t,y,t') = -i\theta(t-t')\langle \Omega_{0}, a_{x}(t)a_{x}^{*}(t')\Omega_{0}\rangle$$
   where $\Omega_{0}$ is the vacuum state $\Omega_{0}$ of $H$ and $\theta$ the Heaviside theta function. Is this well-defined as a distribution? To me this is not clear.
2. How are these Green functions $G(x,t,y,t')$ related to the (two-point) Wightman functions of axiomatic QFT? Are these the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as quadratic forms, $a^\ast(x)$ and $a(x)$ make perfect sense on the form domain generated by finite linear combinations of n-particle wavefunctions lying in Schwartz space. In fact any normal ordered product of such operators defines a quadratic form. Informally speaking, the creation operator takes an element of the domain into a distributional wavefunction, which you can then pair with an element of the domain to get a number. It is only when you want *operators* that smearing is required.

Now, the answer to the second part of this question is yes, although this is a bit more nontrivial. Informally this should look like a tensor product of distributions. Forget the time dependence for a moment and consider
$G(f, g) = \langle \Omega_0, a(f)a^\ast(g)\Omega_0\rangle$. By the Schwartz nuclear theorem this gives a distribution in double the number of variables, so it's sufficient to show that it's a distribution in each component separately. By the CCRs: $= \langle f, g\rangle$. The fact that it's a distribution is then follows from the inner product on the single-particle space. For nonrelativistic quantum mechanics it's just an $L^2$ inner product which of course gives a distribution. In the Fock space of a relativistic QFT, this is a sobolev inner product, which is of course also continuous.

As for the conection to the Wightman functions, these are basically a special case. It's less natural to use Fock space terms in interacting rel-QFTs because of Haag's theorem, but for a free field $\phi = a+a^\ast$, you do in fact have that $\langle\phi(f)\phi(g)\rangle =\langle\Omega_0, a(f)a^\ast(g)\Omega_0\rangle= \langle f, (\Box+m^2)^{-1}g\rangle$, which is the aforementioned sobolev inner product.

Comment: Hi Prox, thanks for your answer. I still am a bit confused with point 1. How can it be well defines as forms if you can produce things like products of Dirac deltas? See e.g. my other question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/801873/green-function-and-probability-amplitude

Comment: The intuition to keep in mind is that the creation operators act by *tensor products*. Thus the product of Dirac deltas that you are worried about is a tensor product of Dirac deltas, which is perfectly well defined. Each variable labels the position of a different particle's wavefunction. Alternatively if you want to think of it in terms of products of distributions on the same domain, then the tensor product story is equivalent to the Dirac deltas having disjoint wavefront sets. For such pairs of distributions, there is a sensible notion of multiplication.