# Green function and probability amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, greens-functions, many-body

Consider the following Green function:
$$G_{2}(x,t,x',t') = \langle \Omega_{0}, e^{itH_{0}}a_{x}e^{-itH_{0}}e^{it' H_{0}}a_{x'}^{*}e^{-it' H_{0}}\Omega_{0}\rangle$$
for $t' > t$. Here, $a_{x}^{*}$ and $a_{x}$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$) denote the creation and annihilation operators on a fermionic Fock space and $\Omega_{0}$ denotes the Fock space vacuum. I am considering a free theory, so $H_{0}$ is a free Hamiltonian and thus satisfies $H_{0}\Omega_{0} = 0$.

I can rewrite the above function as:
$$G_{2}(x,t,x',t') = \langle e^{it H_{0}}a_{x}^{*}\Omega_{0}, e^{it'H_{0}}a_{x'}^{*}\Omega_{0}\rangle.$$

The action of the creation operator is:
$$(a^{*}_{x}f)_{n}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j+1}\delta(x-x_{j})f_{n-1}(x_{1},...,\hat{x}_{j},...,x_{n}),$$
where the hat $\hat{x}_{j}$ means to omit this variable. Thus, I assume that when applied to the vacuum it produces:
$$a_{x}^{*}\Omega_{0} = \delta(x)$$
which is interpreted as an eigenstate of $x$. Hence, $e^{itH_{0}}a_{x}^{*}\Omega_{0} = e^{itH_{0}}\delta(x) =:\psi(x,t)$ is the time evolution of this eigenstate.

My question is: if everything I did is correct and there is no other variable to integrate out, it seems that we have:
$$G_{2}(x,t,x',t') = \langle e^{it H_{0}}a_{x}^{*}\Omega_{0}, e^{it'H_{0}}a_{x'}^{*}\Omega_{0}\rangle = e^{itH_{0}}\delta(x)e^{it'H_{0}}\delta(x').$$
Is this correct? It is an awkward expression. How should I interpret it? On one hand, if I write it as a function $\psi(x,t)$ as before, it looks like some sort of transition probability $\langle \psi(x,t), \psi(x',t')\rangle$. But I can't exactly state its meaning. Specially because the product of deltas $e^{itH_{0}}\delta(x)e^{it'H_{0}}\delta(x')$ looks awkward to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong here.  Firstly, you shouldn't use $x$ as both a label for $a^*_x$ and the position variable that's the argument of $\delta(x)$—it'd be better to do something like asking about $a^*_x$ when $y$ is our position operator/coordinate, and then you could write $a^*_x \Omega_0 = \delta(y-x)$.  This confusion is usually avoided in calculations like this by staying in Fock space and not writing out single-particle wavefunctions—for instance, you also wouldn't be able to write out a wavefunction for $\Omega_0$ because it's not a single-particle state.  My notation of choice would probably be just sticking with $a^\dagger_x|{\Omega_0}\rangle$ and leaving it at that, knowing that what that means is a single-particle state in which the single particle is perfectly localized at position $x$.

The last expression is wrong—you should have an integral over position because of the inner product, which was hard to see because of your previous notational choice with delta functions, so it should be something like
\begin{align*}
G_2(x,t,x^\prime,t^\prime) &= \langle e^{i t H_0} a^*_x \Omega_0, e^{i t^\prime H_0} a^*_{x^\prime} \Omega_0 \rangle\\
&= \int dy (e^{i t H_0} \delta(y-s)) (e^{i t^\prime H_0} \delta(y-x^\prime)).
\end{align*}
Another reason this looks odd is that the Hamiltonians are operators, so they're going to smear out the delta functions, making this something like the convolution of two Gaussians, which is much more reasonable to ask about than the integral of two delta functions against each other.

Comment: Rokas, thanks! That was a very nice answer. Does the final expression have an interpretation? Maybe the probability amplitude of a particle at $x$ at $t$ be found at $x'$ at a later time $t'$ is correct?

Comment: That's exactly it!  You may have to mess with causality to distinguish between the advanced, retarded, Feynman, etc. propagators, which in your calculation would correspond to adding different infinitesimal imaginary factors $i \eta$ to the Hamiltonian to move the poles off of the real axis... but these are details; that interpretation is essentially correct.